# pyrogram - Telegram API to get live location update

Tags: python, telegram, pyrogram

I tried to get the live location update using below pyrogram API code, but getting None in location variable.

```
from pyrogram import Client
from pyrogram import filters

app = Client("my_account",api_id=API_ID,api_hash=API_HASH)

@app.on_message(filters.location)
async def location(client, message):
    print("Location received...")
    print(message.location)
app.run()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you want get location object ?

```
message.location.latitude
message.location.longitude
```

`https://docs.pyrogram.org/api/types/Location#pyrogram.types.Location`